# ruby: add boundaries \b option when using Regexp.union (array)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a regex matcher using:

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.union(some_hash.keys))
```

is it possible to add a boundaries filter to each element of the array so I have:

```
/\bkey1\b|\bkey2\b|,....../
```

Answer (score 2):

For regexp keys:

```
Regexp.union(some_hash.keys.map { |k| /\b#{k}\b/ })
```

or for literal keys:

```
Regexp.union(some_hash.keys.map { |k| /\b#{Regexp.escape(k)}\b/ })
```

The result of `Regexp.union` is already a `Regexp`, no need for `Regexp.new`. In fact, we can also use plain strings inside `Regexp.union`, the difference being we don't initialise the flags in each subexpression:

```
Regexp.union(some_hash.keys.map { |k| "\\b#{k}\\b" })
Regexp.union(some_hash.keys.map { |k| "\\b#{Regexp.escape(k)}\\b" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate regex in simplest way without using `Regexp` as

```
hash = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4}
/\b#{hash.keys.join('\b|\b')}\b/
=>/\ba\b|\bb\b|\bc\b|\bd\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly but you can use the [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-scan) method ...

for example:-

```
a = "cruel world"
a.scan(/\w+/)        #=> ["cruel", "world"]
a.scan(/.../)        #=> ["cru", "el ", "wor"]
a.scan(/(...)/)      #=> [["cru"], ["el "], ["wor"]]
a.scan(/(..)(..)/)   #=> [["cr", "ue"], ["l ", "wo"]]
```